How to enable Step Filtering in VSCode from the TestExplorer?
In VSCode I can debug JUnit tests directly from the TestExplorer or the context menu. But how would I enable StepFiltering for such a scenario? It looks like for step filtering I need to create a launch config, but I cannot figure out how to connect that to running tests from the explorer.
Thanks!

Turns out this setting https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-test/issues/1152#issuecomment-836406638 does the trick
